# How to get bounding box for styled data in vector tiles

Tags: mapbox, react-map-gl, vector-tiles

I have a vector tileset (e.g. all the countries in the world).
Separately, I am running a query that gets a count for each country (e.g. how many times has X occurred in a given country).
Using the query response data, I create a choropleth of the result by correlating the country ids in the query with the country ids in the tiles.

Oftentimes, only a handful of countries are styled (other countries have a zero count).  I would like to initialize the viewport to only those countries that have been styled, however...

I do not know how to obtain the geographic data (e.g. bounding box) of the countries that have been styled.  The query only responds with the country codes and a count (no geographic data).

Is it possible to get the geographic data from the vector tiles themselves?

UPDATE:

I added the bounding box data to each feature in the vector tileset, but I'm still not sure how I would query the tiles to get the list of relevant bounding boxes (e.g. get a list of all features that have a count > 0).

Maybe with something like [queryRenderedFeatures](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#queryrenderedfeatures)...? (not clear how to use this within the context of `react-map-gl`)